# call a function, inside a for loop, to remove elements in a vector (or list)

Tags: c++, class, vector, memory-management, erase-remove-idiom

```
vector<node>::iterator it;
for(it;it!=vector_of_node.end();it++){
    if(it->get_name()=="MARIA"){
        vector_of_node.erase(it);
}
```

i hope the goal of my code is clear. i want to eliminate multiple objects (which are described in a class called node) from a vector (vector_of_nodes in this case).
when i run my code i don't get any error from the compliler but i got a fail while it's running. i'm sure that the error is on this portion of code that i've shared. can you hel me?

Comment: Erasing from a vector invalidates the iterator you are using. You could perhaps iterate using indices by starting at the end and going towards the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing while iterating is possible if you increment the iterator inside the loop depending on if you erase the element or not. If you erase it, the `erase` method returns the next iterator in the vector, if not, increment it yourself. Moreover, you need to initialize the iterator to `begin`.

```
vector<node>::iterator it;
for(it=vector_of_node.begin();it!=vector_of_node.end();){
    if(it->get_name()=="MARIA")
        it = vector_of_node.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: so with the erase method i can point to the next element of the vector and at the same time delete the pointed element?

Comment: @FrancescoDeSantis That's correct. Internally, it first keeps the next iterator in a temporary variable, erase the given object, then returns the next iterator.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sorry, i don't get it. can you explain me wath you said?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Haha that's what I was thinking, I couldn't see the link with what I said

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 i have just read you comment, don't worry ahahah

Comment: thank you @ Gilles-Philippe Paillé now it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

With your current approach, i.e., erasing elements in the vector one by one, all the elements after the erased one have to be moved to the *front* of the vector. This is done for every iteration that erases an element (no movement of elements only if you erase the *back* of the vector).

As an alternative, you may want to consider the [*Erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove). It is better suited if you intend to remove multiple elements from an `std::vector`.

```
// predicate (C++14 for generic lambda)
auto is_maria = [](auto elem) {
   return elem.get_name() == "MARIA";
};  

auto end = std::remove_if(vector_of_node.begin(), vector_of_node.end(), is_maria); 
vector_of_node.erase(end, vector_of_node.end());
```

The idea is to leave the elements you want to erase at the back of the vector and then remove then from the vector with a single `erase()` call to the corresponding overload that takes a range (i.e., an iterator pair).

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating multiple objects in a vector by erasing one at a time is very inefficient.  Each `erase` call will shuffle all elements on the right by one position.  There is already a standard library pattern to do this better, using [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_if):

```
std::erase(std::remove_if(vector_of_node.begin(),
                          vector_of_node.end(),
                          [](const node& n) { return n->get_name() == "MARIA"; }),
           vector_of_node.end());
```

The result of `std::remove_if` is the vector rearranged with all matches moved to the end, and it returns an iterator to the first of the matches.  You then call `std::erase` to remove them all.